# Proportional allocation in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

The essence of the task is to make a distribution on available debts by D_Date (year, month).

```
- D_Date -- Amount  A_Rest
------------------------------
2018-12-05  150,00  150,00
2018-12-08  100,00  100,00
2018-12-21  30,00   30,00
2019-01-05  165,00  165,00
2019-01-08  110,00  110,00
2019-01-21  55,00   55,00
2019-02-05  165,00  165,00
2019-02-08  110,00  110,00
2019-02-21  55,00   55,00
```

With input @payment = 200,00
Expect result:

```
- D_Date -- Amount  A_Rest
-------------------------------
2018-12-05  150,00  42,84
2018-12-08  100,00  28,58
2018-12-21  30,00   8,58     __ 201812
2019-01-05  165,00  165,00
2019-01-08  110,00  110,00
2019-01-21  55,00   55,00    __ 201901
2019-02-05  165,00  165,00
2019-02-08  110,00  110,00
2019-02-21  55,00   55,00    __ 201902
```

As a result, only 1 month (there are 3 rows in first month) was used, because the amount in @payment was not enough to pay all debts

@payment = 200
I tried to solve this problem in the following way - output the sum of debts by month (SUM)A_Rest OVER (PARTITION BY D_Date) AS total and then Payment - total, as a result I got just data that cannot be converted to a proportional distribution over the table.

```
Amount - amount of a particular payment
Total - total amount of all payments (280)
Initial_Amount - initial amount of payment (200)
```

```
Substituting values:

For a line with date 2018-12-05:
A_Rest_new = (150 / 280) * 200 = 107.14 ≈ 42.84

For the row with date 2018-12-08:
A_Rest_new = (100 / 280) * 200 = 71.43 ≈ 28.58

For the row with date 2018-12-21:
A_Rest_new = (30 / 280) * 200 = 21.43 ≈ 8.58
```

That is, the amount in the A_Rest column is distributed in proportion to the payment amounts in the Amount column relative to the original payment amount of 200.

```
declare @payment money = 200.00;
declare @F_Subscr int = 1;
SELECT DISTINCT 
     d_date
    ,N_Amount
    ,N_Amount_Rest - ((N_Amount_Rest / SUM(N_Amount_Rest) OVER (PARTITION BY d_date) ) * @payment ) as N_Amount_Rest
    
FROM 

(
SELECT 
     FORMAT(D_Date, 'yyyyMM') d_date
     ,N_Amount
     ,N_Amount_Rest
FROM
    dbo.FD_Bills
WHERE
    F_Subscr = @F_Subscr

) tt
```

The code above result:

```
D_Date -N_Amount-N_Amount_Rest
-----------------------------
201812  30,00   8,58
201812  100,00  28,58
201812  150,00  42,86
201901  55,00   21,68
201901  110,00  43,34
201901  165,00  65,00
201902  55,00   21,68
201902  110,00  43,34
201902  165,00  65,00
```

Scenarios:

- If @payment = 280:

```
- D_Date -- Amount  A_Rest
------------------------------
2018-12-05  150,00  0,00
2018-12-08  100,00  0,00
2018-12-21  30,00   0,00
2019-01-05  165,00  165,00
2019-01-08  110,00  110,00
2019-01-21  55,00   55,00
2019-02-05  165,00  165,00
2019-02-08  110,00  110,00
2019-02-21  55,00   55,00
```

- if @payment = 430:

```
- D_Date -- Amount  A_Rest
------------------------------
2018-12-05  150,00  0,00
2018-12-08  100,00  0,00
2018-12-21  30,00   0,00
2019-01-05  165,00  90,00
2019-01-08  110,00  60,00
2019-01-21  55,00   30,01
2019-02-05  165,00  165,00
2019-02-08  110,00  110,00
2019-02-21  55,00   55,00
```

- if @payment = 940:

```
 - D_Date -- Amount  A_Rest
------------------------------
2018-12-05  150,00  0,00
2018-12-08  100,00  0,00
2018-12-21  30,00   0,00
2019-01-05  165,00  0,00
2019-01-08  110,00  0,00
2019-01-21  55,00   0,00
2019-02-05  165,00  0,00
2019-02-08  110,00  0,00
2019-02-21  55,00   0,00
```

Comment: Please give the desired results for several different payment values, including the calculations of how the desired results were calculated; [mre] *(Please actually read the linked help page)*

Comment: Hey, i expand my question. Could you take a look please?

Comment: There is a table with 3 columns `Date`, `Amount`, `Rest`. You  need to create a procedure with one parameter `@payment` and as a result you want to proportionally decrease a debt month by month? Am I right?

Comment: Yeah, your are right

Comment: Why have you deducted the amount only from the first month? If the amount was 300, would you deduct 20 from the second month? Will there always be three rows per month? Why are you using format to turn dates in to strings?

Comment: If the original amount paid all the debts in the first month, the balance would start paying the debts from the next month

Comment: Please edit your question to demonstrate all scenarios / information you have added in comments.

Comment: @MatBailie I added a couple scenarios to the end. Please take a look

Comment: From a previous comment ; ***Will there always be three rows per month? Why are you using format to turn dates in to strings?***

Comment: I use it to sort by only year and month, not year-month-day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a potential solution which doesn't use recursive CTEs:

```sql
SELECT  *
INTO #data
FROM
(
    VALUES  (N'2018-12-05', 150.00,150.00)
    ,   (N'2018-12-08', 100.00,100.00)
    ,   (N'2018-12-21', 30.00,30.00)
    ,   (N'2019-01-05', 165.00,165.00)
    ,   (N'2019-01-08', 110.00,110.00)
    ,   (N'2019-01-21', 55.00,55.00)
    ,   (N'2019-02-05', 165.00,165.00)
    ,   (N'2019-02-08', 110.00,110.00)
    ,   (N'2019-02-21', 55.00,55.00)
) t (D_Date,Amount,A_Rest)

DECLARE @x float = 430 -- change amount here

;WITH data AS(
    SELECT  d_date
    ,   monthYearSum
    ,   CASE WHEN accSum <= @x THEN monthYearSum ELSE @x - (accSum - monthyearSum) END AS lagSum
    FROM    (
        SELECT  MIN(D_Date) AS d_date
        ,   SUM(amount) AS monthYearSum
        ,   SUM(SUM(amount)) OVER(ORDER BY year(d_date), MONTH(d_date)) AS accSum
        FROM    #data
        GROUP BY YEAR(d_date), MONTH(d_date)
    ) x
)
SELECT  CASE WHEN lagSum > 0 THEN amount / monthYearSum  * lagSum * 1.0 ELSE 0 END AS Paid
,   CASE WHEN lagSum > 0 THEN amount - (amount / monthYearSum  * lagSum * 1.0) ELSE Amount END AS rest
,   dd.*
FROM    data d
INNER JOIN #data dd
    ON  YEAR(dd.D_Date) = YEAR(d.d_date)
    AND MONTH(dd.d_date) = MONTH(d.d_date)
```

I create an aggregated month / year data CTE which contains amount per month/year as well as accumulated amount per month/year.

For each month/year period, you want to know how much money can actually be distributed. This is calculated by: `CASE WHEN accSum <= @x THEN monthYearSum ELSE @x - (accSum - monthyearSum) END`, either total monthyear amount, or part of it just covering @x.

Finally, you do the distribution by creating distribution of amount `(amount / monthYearSum)` and multiplying with the actual amount used `lagSum`.

Edit: alternative version that avoids self join:

```sql
WITH data AS(
    SELECT  *
    ,   CASE WHEN accSum <= @x THEN monthYearSum ELSE @x - (accSum - monthyearSum) END AS lagSum
    FROM    (
        SELECT  *
        ,   SUM(case when rnk = 1 then monthYearSum end) OVER(ORDER BY year(d_date), month(d_date) ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS accSum
        FROM    (
            SELECT  SUM(amount) over(partition by year(d_date), month(d_date)) AS monthYearSum
            ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by year(d_date), month(d_date) order by @@spid) AS rnk
            ,   *
            FROM    #data
        ) x
    ) x
)
SELECT  CASE WHEN lagSum > 0 THEN amount / monthYearSum  * lagSum * 1.0 ELSE 0 END AS Paid
,   CASE WHEN lagSum > 0 THEN amount - (amount / monthYearSum  * lagSum * 1.0) ELSE Amount END AS rest
,   *
FROM    data d
```

Comment: @MatBailie, you're right, added another version

Comment: Nesting as well as CTEs?  Sub-queries named `x`?  I'll upvote when you at-least get rid of the `x`? :)

Comment: What's wrong with "x"? :D I always use it when the alias doesn't matter

Comment: The second solution was easier to understand, I decided to use it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE FD_Bills (
  F_Subscr    INT,
  D_Date      DATE,
  Amount      DECIMAL(15,2),
  A_Rest      DECIMAL(15,2)
);

INSERT INTO
  FD_Bills
VALUES
  (1, '2018-12-05', 150.00, 150.00),
  (1, '2018-12-08', 100.00, 100.00),
  (1, '2018-12-21',  30.00,  30.00),
  (1, '2019-01-05', 165.00, 165.00),
  (1, '2019-01-08', 110.00, 110.00),
  (1, '2019-01-21',  55.00,  55.00),
  (1, '2019-02-05', 150.00, 150.00),
  (1, '2019-02-08', 100.00, 100.00),
  (1, '2019-02-21',  30.00,  30.00)
;
```

```
DECLARE @payment DECIMAL(15,2) = 611.00;

WITH
  monthly(F_Subscr, D_Date, Amount, month_total, month_to_date, to_date) AS
(
  SELECT
    F_Subscr, D_Date, Amount,
    SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY F_Subscr, YEAR(D_Date), MONTH(D_Date)),
    SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY F_Subscr, YEAR(D_Date), MONTH(D_Date)
                          ORDER BY D_Date),
    SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY F_Subscr
                          ORDER BY D_Date)
  FROM
    FD_Bills
),
  calculations AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    @payment - (to_date - month_to_date)   AS payment_for_this_month
  FROM
    monthly
)
SELECT
  *,
  CASE
    WHEN payment_for_this_month <= 0           THEN Amount
    WHEN payment_for_this_month >= month_total THEN 0
    ELSE
      Amount
      -
      payment_for_this_month * Amount / month_total
  END
    AS A_Rest
FROM
  calculations  
WHERE
  F_Subscr = 1
ORDER BY
  F_Subscr,
  D_Date
```

| F_Subscr | D_Date | Amount | A_Rest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2018-12-05 | 150.00 | 0.000000 |
| 1 | 2018-12-08 | 100.00 | 0.000000 |
| 1 | 2018-12-21 | 30.00 | 0.000000 |
| 1 | 2019-01-05 | 165.00 | 0.000000 |
| 1 | 2019-01-08 | 110.00 | 0.000000 |
| 1 | 2019-01-21 | 55.00 | 0.000000 |
| 1 | 2019-02-05 | 150.00 | 149.464286 |
| 1 | 2019-02-08 | 100.00 | 99.642858 |
| 1 | 2019-02-21 | 30.00 | 29.892858 |

Note, if rounded to 2 decimal places, all three `A_Rest` rows round Down.
This means that 0.01 would go missing.
There are numerous scenarios where this rounding error would occur.

If that matters, use the version below...

---

---

Same method as above, with one difference

```
-- Payment for a row == Payment for all rows  UPTO  this one
--                      MINUS
--                      Payment for all rows BEFORE this one
```

This ensures that when rows are rounded, they all add up to exactly the right amount.

```
DECLARE @payment DECIMAL(15,2) = 611.00;

WITH
  monthly(F_Subscr, D_Date, Amount, month_total, month_to_date, to_date) AS
(
  SELECT
    F_Subscr, D_Date, Amount,
    SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY F_Subscr, YEAR(D_Date), MONTH(D_Date)),
    SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY F_Subscr, YEAR(D_Date), MONTH(D_Date)
                          ORDER BY D_Date),
    SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY F_Subscr
                          ORDER BY D_Date)
  FROM
    FD_Bills
),
  calculations AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    @payment - (to_date - month_to_date)   AS payment_for_this_month
  FROM
    monthly
)
SELECT
  *,
  CASE
    WHEN payment_for_this_month <= 0           THEN Amount
    WHEN payment_for_this_month >= month_total THEN 0
    ELSE
      Amount
      -
      CAST(
        ROUND(payment_for_this_month * (month_to_date         ) / month_total, 2)
        -
        ROUND(payment_for_this_month * (month_to_date - Amount) / month_total, 2)
        AS
        DECIMAL(15,2)
      )
  END
    AS A_Rest
FROM
  calculations  
WHERE
  F_Subscr = 1
ORDER BY
  F_Subscr,
  D_Date
```

| F_Subscr | D_Date | Amount | A_Rest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2018-12-05 | 150.00 | 0.00 |
| 1 | 2018-12-08 | 100.00 | 0.00 |
| 1 | 2018-12-21 | 30.00 | 0.00 |
| 1 | 2019-01-05 | 165.00 | 0.00 |
| 1 | 2019-01-08 | 110.00 | 0.00 |
| 1 | 2019-01-21 | 55.00 | 0.00 |
| 1 | 2019-02-05 | 150.00 | 149.46 |
| 1 | 2019-02-08 | 100.00 | 99.65 |
| 1 | 2019-02-21 | 30.00 | 29.89 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lqJs8KIO)

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help me!
For noob like me your code looks to complex :(

Comment: @Quaka - it's essentially the same as the one you accepted, just laid out differently.  Also, I'm about to add an edit which removes rounding errors.